# is the set of all recurring decimal numbers countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

we can express all recurring numbers as rational numbers
and as we know that all rational numbers are countable. 
so can we say that this set is countable?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to say something about the rationals that have two decimal expansions.  For example, $\frac 12=0.50000\ldots = 0.49999\ldots $.  That means you don't yet have a bijection.  But if you know twice a countable set is still countable you can just point out that no rational has more than two expansions and you are done.

Comment: You really don't. Subsets of countable sets tend to be countable.